# Should I use cross-validation to build an explanatory model?

Tags: multiple-regression, cross-validation, explanatory-models

I know it is recommended to do so for a predictive model, but if I am trying to study a potentially causal relationship and adjusting for covariates to be able to isolate that relationship should I use cross-validation during model building?

Or should I build my model off of theory/DAG?